# How are meteoroids, asteroids and debris in space tracked?

Tags: spacecraft, debris, interplanetary, meteorites

How far, small, and fast can meteors be detected?

Comment: I removed the 2nd question as answers to it will be unrelated. Detection is carried out by radar, lidar, optical telescopes etc from Earth and space. Evasion is an entirely separate question

Comment: @Hobbes okay that's great! Nicely done too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Space debris is tracked via radar](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10905/how-does-a-spacecraft-such-as-soyuz-detect-when-its-on-collision-course-with-an).

Asteroids are usually tracked via [optical telescopes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waK0pMP4nQM) set up for that purpose. If they get really close to Earth, they may be tracked via the space debris systems too. In some cases, [extra observations are arranged](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18958/how-accurate-can-near-earth-asteroids-be-tracked/19087?s=12%7C10.1403#19087) for asteroids that look like they may get close to Earth.

Meteoroids are too small to be tracked at long range. [There are some efforts underway](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cx91mZHeYKE) to record the trails they leave when entering the atmosphere.

[Nice animation of asteroid discoveries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKKg4lZ_o-Y)

Comment: Scott Manley's videos rock! I've asked a question about this one: [Why did the distribution of asteroids discovered in 2010 have a radial modulation?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/25736/7982)